# Mariadb replication - Ignore users changes

Tags: mysql, replication, mariadb, linux, debian

I posted this question on ServerFault but was told to ask it here.

I need to set up multi-source replication (3 masters and 1 slave). I'd like to avoid replicating users' changes on the slave because it breaks replication.

I've followed this : https://serverfault.com/questions/865487/mysql-replication-failing-on-mysql-user-changes but it didn't seem to work.

I've tried different configurations but none works.

- Ignore table mysql on the slave :

```
replicate_ignore_db=mysql
```

- Ignore table mysql for each connection on the slave:

```
master1.replicate_ignore_db=mysql
master2.replicate_ignore_db=mysql
master3.replicate_ignore_db=mysql
```

- Ignore the mysql table in the master's binlog :

```
binlog-ignore-db=mysql
```

I'm working with Mariadb 10.6 on Debian 9. The master's binlog format is ROW.

I'm still getting errors in the replication regarding users changes. How can I make the replication ignore the users' changes ?

Comment: (Yes, this is a better place for this type of question.)  You want to block _all_ writes to `mysql` from replicating?  Show an example of a query that is causing trouble, and the error message.

Answer (score 0):

As user changing SQL like `ALTER USER` etc is replicated as a statement, to prevent the replication of those, use `SET SQL_LOG_BIN=0` in the session where the SQL is executed. Sorry, replication filtering won't help.

ref: [sql_log_bin in Knowledge base](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/replication-and-binary-log-system-variables/#sql_log_bin).